# PHPUnit: No test executed with a seemingly good config file

Tags: phpunit

I get the message *no tests executed* when i try to do

```
phpunit
```

or

```
phpunit -c phpunit.xml
```

on the other hand, if i do

```
phpunit -c phpunit.xml ./tests
```

It works. But this is a problem considering that some tool that I'm using does not handle this well.

Directory structur
  *code*
  tests/
  phpunit.xml
  autoloader.php

And here is the config file

```
<phpunit backupGlobals="false"
         backupStaticAttributes="false"
         colors="true"
         convertErrorsToExceptions="true"
         convertNoticesToExceptions="true"
         convertWarningsToExceptions="true"
         processIsolation="false"
         stopOnFailure="false"
         syntaxCheck="true"
         bootstrap="./tests/bootstrap.php"
        >
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="StdTestSuite">
            <directory>
                tests/
            </directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
</phpunit>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the stupidest thing ever.
You can't have whitespace inside the  tag.
So what you need to have in you phpunit.xml file is this

```
   ...
   <testsuite name="StdTestSuite">
       <directory>tests/</directory>
   </testsuite>
   ...
```

Then running

```
phpunit
```

Should work